# Pydantic V2 allow validator to annotate potential input argument types

Tags: python, pydantic, pydantic-v2

With a Pydantic V2 BaseModel, I'm trying to allow multiple data types to be input but are parsed to a specific type via `@field_validator`. For example:

```py
from typing import Iterable

class Example(BaseModel):
    my_string: str   # Will always become str due to field_validator
    
    @field_validator('my_string', mode='before')
    @classmethod
    def parse_my_string(cls, value: str | Iterable[str]) -> str:   # Allow both str and Iterable[str]
        if isinstance(value, str):
            return value
        else:
            return ', '.join(value)
```

but now if I try to instantiate it with an Iterable, it (Pylance) gives me red squigglies:

```py
Example(my_string=['A', 'B', 'C'])
```

> Argument of type "list[str]" cannot be assigned to parameter "my_string" of type "str" in function "**init**"
> "list[str]" is incompatible with "str" `Pylance(reportArgumentType)`

How can I make it look to the field_validator method for potential input types?

I would hope/expect that validators can be checked for potential input argument types.

Comment: I don't think there is a way for Pylance to automatically deduce anything from your validator - The only way here would be to redefine the `__init__` function with proper values and forward to `super().__init__`.

Comment: Have you tried to use `typing.overload` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#overload) to extend the annotation for `__init__`?